# Как описать функцию, принимающую разные типы аргументов?

Tags: golang

Я хочу создать мапу, ключи которой — это строки, а значения ― это функции:

```golang
var Items map[string]func(a string, b string) bool
```

В коде нужно будет вызывать функцию в зависимости от переданной строки.

Проблема в том что при объявлении мапы *Go* требует точно описывать типы аргументов. Что делать если мне нужно добавить в мап функцию с другими типами и количеством входящих аргументов? Как это решается?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Во-первых, я бы сказал, что ваш дизайн попахивает недоработкой
архитектуры.  То, что вы описываете, может быть нормальным шаблоном
в динамически-типизированном языке типа *Python* или *Ruby*,
но никак не в *Go*.

Во-вторых, вы можете использовать в качестве значений хеш-таблицы пустые
интерфейсы и конвертировать их в нужный тип на месте вызова с помощью
утверждений типа (англ «*type assertion*»):

```golang
var Items map[string]interface{}

// …

var sf = Items["someStringFunction"].(func(string) bool)
var if = Items["someIntFunction"].(func(int) bool)
```

Вы по сути превращаете часть своего кода в динамически-типизированную.
Цена: паники и прочая обработка ошибок типов.